# Break promise-chain execution on error [Duplicated]

Tags: javascript, angular, promise

I am trying to break out of the promise chain execution when it failed, but it still compiles the chain, however, an error has occurred in a specific method.

```
this.addParticipantByEmail(email, type)
        .then(() => this.issueIdentity(email, type))
        .then(cardData => this.dataService.importWallet(cardData))
        .then(() => this.authService.signupUser(email, password, type))
        .then( () => {
          this.spinner.hide();
        })
        .catch(error => {
          if (error === "Server error") {
            return (this.errorMessage =
              "Could not connect to REST server. Please check your configuration details");
          } else {
            return (this.errorMessage = error);
          }
        });


addParticipantByEmail(email: string, type: string): Promise<any> {
    this.initiateParticipant(email, type);
    // Add the participant using the admin account to the Blockchain through COMPOSER-REST-API
    return this.service
      .addParticipantAsAdmin(this.participant)
      .toPromise()
      .catch(error => {
        if (error === "Server error") {
          this.errorMessage =
            "Could not connect to REST server. Please check your configuration details";
        } else {
          this.errorMessage = error;
        }
      });
  }
```

I want to stop the promise chain when an error occurs in one of those promises.

Comment: it is already the case. you problem here is that `addParticipantByEmail` actually never fails as it catches the failure. To make it "propagate" the failure, you should `return Promise.reject(this.errorMessage)` in the `catch` callback.

Comment: Don't catch in the function definition. Stop at `.toPromise();` Allow the caller to catch.

Comment: @Julien Barrois, thank you for your answer, please if I need to put Promise.reject(this.errorMessage) in the promise-chain catch or in the function definition, thank's